# Use Python to parse comma separated string with text delimiter coming from stdin

Tags: string, csv, stdin

I have a csv file that is being fed to my Python script via stdin.

This is a comma separated file with quotations as text delimiter.

Here is an example line:

```
457,"Last,First",NYC
```

My script so far, splits each line by looking for commas, but how do I make it aware of the text delimiter quotes?

My current script:

```
for line in sys.stdin:   
    line = line.strip()
    line.split(',')
    print line
```

The code splits the name into two since it does not recognize the quotations enclosing that text field. I need the name to remain as a single element.

If it matters, the data is being fed through stdin within a hadoop-streaming program.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do it more manually, with something like this:

```
row = []
enclosed = False
word = ''
for character in sys.stdin:        
    if character == '"':
        enclosed = not enclosed
    elif character = ',' and not enclosed:
        row.append(word)
        word = ''
    else:
        word += character
```

Haven't tested nor thought about it for too long but seems to me it could work. Probably someone more into Pythonist sintax could fine something better for doing the trick although ;)

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to answer my own question. If I read right, it may be possible to send a streaming input into csv reader like so:

```
for line in csv.reader(sys.stdin): 
    print line
```